# jetty log per context

Tags: logging, configuration, jetty

I'm running few applications in a jetty server, each application has it's own context file in the /contexts folder, and each application specifies it's own log file.

When starting jetty, all applications are started, and working, all the log files are created, however - the all the output is emitted to the last log-file that was created, where the others stay empty.

The part that describes the logging for every context looks as follows.
I tried to make sure that each context has it's own ids, and names - but still - the problem remains.

```
  <New id="oGMRLog2" class="java.io.PrintStream">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
        <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/testlogs/std2.yyyy_mm_dd.log</Arg>
        <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
        <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
        <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT+2</Arg></Call></Arg>
        <Get id="oGM2ReqLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
  <Call class="org.mortbay.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Redirecting GM stderr/stdout to <Ref id="oGM2ReqLogName"/></Arg></Call>
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref id="oGMRLog2"/></Arg></Call>
  <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref id="oGMRLog2"/></Arg></Call>
```

I start to suspect that the problem is in `class="java.lang.System"`, where the print stream should be attached to this context alone, and not to the entire JVM

Can anybody show me what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Web) Context based logging can be accomplished configuring Jetty to using [Slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), then configuring logback with the [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) configuration, that uses information from a [MDCHandler](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-and-logback-example/blob/master/jetty-slf4j-mdc-handler/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/examples/logging/MDCHandler.java) to [sift according to context of the deployed webapp](https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-and-logback-example/blob/master/jetty-distro-with-logback-sifting/src/main/config/resources/logback.xml).

It is documented at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback

There is even a sample project showing this in action available at https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-and-logback-example

Comment: Hi Joakim! Can you be specific? I added
    MDC.put("context", request.getContextPath());
to (org.eclipse.jetty.examples.logging.)MDCHandler.handle() but context is always null. Therefore it cannot be used for any sifting...

Comment: @LiborJelinek you can't use the `request.getContextPath()` during the `MDCHandler.handle()` as there is no context (yet).  The context is determined at a later step in the flow.